# Snowpark with GEOMETRY type fails

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpark

I try to parse WKT and create GEOMETRY type with Snowpark Python API, but it fails:

```
session.sql("select to_geometry('POINT(1820.12 890.56)')").show()
```

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

I tested both Version 0.9.0 and 0.8.0, same result

The above SQL works fine in Snowflake's worksheets

Comment: interestingly, ``session.sql("select to_geometry('POINT(1820.12 890.56)')").collect()`` works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Snowpark Python can not handle the output of the geometry objects when showing. This is the failing code in type_utils.py:

```
if column_type_name == "DECIMAL" or (
    (column_type_name == "FIXED" or column_type_name == "NUMBER") and scale != 0
):
    if precision != 0 or scale != 0:
        if precision > DecimalType._MAX_PRECISION:
            return DecimalType(
                DecimalType._MAX_PRECISION,
                scale + precision - DecimalType._MAX_SCALE,
            )
        else:
            return DecimalType(precision, scale)
    else:
        return DecimalType(38, 18)
```

The code fails when it can't determine the precision. So adding a check mitigates the issue:

```
if column_type_name == "DECIMAL" or (
    (column_type_name == "FIXED" or column_type_name == "NUMBER") and scale != 0
):
    if precision is None:
        return DecimalType(precision, scale)
    if precision != 0 or scale != 0:
        if precision > DecimalType._MAX_PRECISION:
            return DecimalType(
                DecimalType._MAX_PRECISION,
                scale + precision - DecimalType._MAX_SCALE,
            )
        else:
            return DecimalType(precision, scale)
    else:
        return DecimalType(38, 18)
```

Please submit a support ticket to Snowflake, so the code can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Support of GEOMETRY was added in Snowpark v.1.5.1